# What language is this and how do I run it?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm doing one of those codding maze challenges and I got stuck as I decoded a base64 image which contained a code block that i need to use to progress though, I'm not sure how to use it.(I know nothing about frontend languages so I assume its some form of js or api call)

```
function solutionChecker(url, queryParams, method, headers){

 var a = headers[queryParams.b];
 var altwo = a < 2;

 if(!alttwo){
  headers.clue="output";
 }

return a == c && method === "PATCH";
}
```

Comment: Definitely JavaScript. Need more info regarding your code challenge as to what you are trying to achive? But running it inside an HTML file in your browser as per below is a good start. PATCH is an HTTP verb used to alter parts of a message. So you must have some sort of URL as input and some parameters to send it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_verb

Comment: @Neville Yeah thats what threw me of 'PATCH' being a http verb, and that the variables were url queryParams method and headers(it seemed to me like they were predefined objects of a particular language).  Though if its just vanila javascript I need to keep on digging. Thanks

Comment: I decoded the string in this page to get the code snippet https://welcome-to-the-maze.herokuapp.com/simplicity/CleverdeerPenguins0_0 . You can use this to decode it https://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp . Hope that provides enough context

Comment: Did you ever progress through the maze? I'm stuck at 3/5 with a similar problem that you were facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like javascript.

You can embed in a simple html and try it.

NOTE: Supply valid parameters to run the function properly...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function otherFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
}

function solutionChecker(url, queryParams, method, headers){

 var a = headers[queryParams.b];
 var altwo = a < 2;

 if(!alttwo){
  headers.clue="output";
 }

return a == c && method === "PATCH";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h2>JavaScript in Head</h2>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="solutionChecker('someUrl',params,'METOD',headers)">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok thanks. My follow up then is I'm unable to run this as I get an error saying params and headers aren't defined. So I guess that means i need to write my own javascript functions to set these objects up?

Comment: Oww sorry, i forgot to mention... you should supply valid  parameters to run function properly.